# Set a Multiline String

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to write a program with Visual Basic 2010.

The problem is when I load an "Example" with multi-lines it takes **forever**! I don't mind it taking a while but it would be nice if there was a faster way.

```
'Open Sample Page
Textbox1.Text =
"<html>" + Environment.NewLine +
"<!- Example ->" + Environment.NewLine +
"<h1 align='center'>" + Environment.NewLine +
"Page Title" + Environment.NewLine +
"</h1>" + Environment.NewLine +
"<h3>" + Environment.NewLine +
"Subject" + Environment.NewLine +
"</h3>" + Environment.NewLine +
"<p>" + Environment.NewLine +
"Paragraph with lots of text in it.<br>" + Environment.NewLine +
"<a href='http://www.google.com/'>" + Environment.NewLine +
"Links" + Environment.NewLine +
"</a>" + Environment.NewLine +
"...And Different lines." + Environment.NewLine +
"</p>" + Environment.NewLine +
"</html>"
```

Comment: What specifically takes a long time? Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: Are you sure you're not simply noticing build time?

Comment: Textbox1.Text=" <HTML> <head>Title</head><body>…ex.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................and go through multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys but this guy on yahoo! helped me..

VB uses can use ampersand(&) or a plus sign (+) operator for concatenation.

The plus(+) operator is also used for addition while the ampersand(&) is only used for concatenation.

When you use the + VB must figure out which operation you are trying to perform, addition or concatenation. Most of the time VB guesses right but there are time when VB can guess wrong and cause a bug. Also since you are using the plus sign VB has to determine which operation needs to be performed.

I recommend that you use the ampersand(&) whenever you are trying to do concatenation and ONLY use the plus sign(+) for addition.

Try replacings all of the +'s with &'s so that VB doesn't waste time in determing if addition or concatenation needs to be done. By using an ampersand you leave no doubt that you want to do concatenation

A quick way to do that edit is to highlight the text and press CTRL+H to do a find and replace on the selected text and replace + with &

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is a known .NET performance sink.  Often, when doing lots of string appending you can increase performance and reduce memory pressure by using the System.Text.StringBuilder class.

```
Dim builder as New StringBuilder()

builder.AppendLine ("<html>") ' automatically appends the NewLine
builder.AppendLine ("<!- Example ->")
builder.AppendLine("<h1 align='center'>")
' the rest of the HTML
TextBox1.Text = builder.ToString()
```

As mentioned in the comments.  It would be helpful to know exactly what your performance problems are in you application.

Comment: Is there anyway i could do somthing like..

    Textbox1.Text =
    ("<html>
    <!- Example ->
    <h1 align='center'>
    Page Title
    </h1>
    <h3>
    Subject
    </h3>
    <p>
    Paragraph with lots of text in it.<br>
    <a href='http://www.google.com/'>
    Links
    </a>
    ...And Different lines.
    </p>
    </html>")

...?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish in your output?  Are you trying to show the text and wrap it to the next line when the output is too long.  Or do you want to control when the text moves to the next line?   Also, you haven't stated what UI framework you are using.  WPF, Silverlight, WinForms, ASP.NET

Comment: I trying to keep from putting + environment.newline +

Comment: Every time(sorry I keep pressing enter to add a new line but I just sumits it)

Comment: After you create a comment you can edit it to make changes, you don't have to create another comment.

Comment: I would like to set my richtextbox1.text to (all the stuff up there) without adding + environment.newline + every time...  I would like to select it all without going...                                                                                                                   "the first line" + environment.newline + "second line" + environment......          Maybe like... ("the first line, second line") or somthing you would use for writing lots of text with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handy little trick using XML Literals to make it easy to enter strings with embedded carriage returns.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2007/10/26/xml-literals-tips-tricks.aspx

```
  Dim s as string = <string>
ID       : <%= Me.ID %>
Name     : <%= Me.LastName %>, <%= Me.FirstName %>
Address  : <%= Me.Address %>
         : <%= Me.City %>, <%= Me.State %> - <%= Me.Zip %>
                    </string>.Value
```

All of the line breaks and formatting will be preserved and you can embed variable data in to the string using an ASP like syntax.